# Cannot find the "GoogleAccountManager" in the google plus example 

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-plus, google-account

While trying the google plus API example from [the project site](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/) I'm completely stuck with one import:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android2.auth.GoogleAccountManager;
```

This thing just doesn't seem to exist in the project.

The sample is a read-made Eclipse project I imported, and to be sure I checked if the massive amount of .jar's in the /lib directory are added to the build path. They are, I can see them listed in the Referenced Libraries part in my Eclipse project.

I can find mentions of `com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android2.auth` but there just doesn't seem to be any `GoogleAccountManager` class around.

Several possibilities I have come up with, but can't find out which is it, let alone find a solution to them:

- I have not set up my project correctly. I doubt it, but completely possible. This would mean that the example has a broken project set-up and/or I managed to not import all libraries?
- The class or package or something like that is renamed // named differently. This would mean the example is broken out of the box, and that I still need to find the correct class (and change the import + calling code to that)
- Something else :D

The following are the contents of the libs directory as you can also browse [on the project page](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/browse/#hg%2Fandroid%2Flibs) . Notice that it does containt `google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar`

```
google-api-client-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-api-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-api-services-plus-v1-1.3.0-beta-sources.jar
google-api-services-plus-v1-1.3.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-http-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-extensions-android3-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-http-client-extensions-android3-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta-sources.jar
google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
gson-1.7.1.jar
guava-r09.jar
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client-googleapis-extensions-android2/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android2/auth/GoogleAccountManager.java?r=293c6f883b157d50adb0fbcefcf1bbfc1bac583f

Comment: Yes. that is the source. But I can hardly just make a new java file and copy past that, can I? :D. There is a jar "google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar" which I suspect is the equivalent of that link, so should contain that class. It is in my build path, but the class isn't there as far as eclipse is conserned. What do you suggest I do? Add a second api-client lib to the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first page is a link to updated Google plus libraries [`google-plus-java-starter_v5.zip`](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/downloads/detail?name=google-plus-java-starter_v5.zip)

**Updated Link:** [`google-plus-java-starter_v5.zip`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/google-api-client/google-api-client-1.9.0-beta-sources.jar.zip)

It contains `android/libs/google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar`, which contains `GoogleAccountManager` class.

As this is an extension it probably needs other jars too.

(summary of comments)
Manually adding `/libs/google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar` to the build path and verifying that it is in the Referenced Libraries fixes the problem. It is unknown (to me (Nanne)) why this doesn't happen automagically when adding the libraries, but there you are.

Comment: I've added the allready imported contents of the lib directory, which you can also check out here: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/browse/#hg%2Fandroid%2Flibs . I believe the file is allready there.

Comment: The class is definitely in the jar. Check with eclipse why it is not including it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out here :). It is in my build path, it is in my referenced libraries, but all I can see for that file is a "AndroidHttp.class"

Comment: If I go to [the file in the example](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/browse/android/libs/google-http-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar) and download it, I don't see that class. Would that mean the sample is broken, and contains an incomplete jar file?

Comment: Because it's not in that jar. It's in android/libs/google-api-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar

Comment: You're absolutely right, I clicked to the wrong place :). but that still doesn't explain why I can't use it.

Comment: It seems that the alike-looking names just add some confusion, and the basic problim is that the file doesn't get added to the build path. Can't seem to figure out why, but redownloading the project etc doesn't help. If I manually add that file to the build path in a new download it does get added. Again, I'm not really sure why, but it works in the end. I'll  accept your answer and add my summary of these comments if you don't mind :)

Comment: Though this seems to have helped as far as "finding" the classes, the final project freezes (FC), presumably because there is still something wrong with the builp path/depencys. It mentions: " _java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport_ ". I can find the line that produces it, and find the source (`NetHttpTransport`) it refers to in my project, but it still crashes. It is this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648039/android-and-google-client-api-nethttptransport-class-not-found . I'll check the libs, but I can find the class allready :(

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on Project, select Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export Tab->click on checkbox for “Android Private Libraries”.  That worked for me.